# If I make a design in RGB mode and then change it to CMYK how will it look when it's printed?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, print-design, rgb

I'm making a business card in Photoshop and it needs to be in CMYK mode. Now, I'm using a logo on it that I previously made for the client in RGB mode and when I put it into the CMYK mode business card design it desaturates it a little. I'm trying to get my head around whether or not it will print how it looks on my screen (ie desaturated) or how it looks when it's in RGB mode? Because, the colours aren't accurate in CMYK mode so if that's exactly how it will look when printed I will need to adjust the colours to look like they do in RGB mode. Sorry if that doesn't make sense - usually I only design logos and I've never run into this problem before.

Comment: "if that's exactly how it will look when printed I will need to adjust the colours to look like they do in RGB mode." This isn't necessarily possible, as bright RGB colours just can't be reproduced in CMYK - see http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/can-you-convert-a-neon-rgb-color-to-cmyk-for-printing

Comment: Also, this issue won't just affect the logo - e.g if you're using black text, it should be pure CMYK black, ie c0 m0 y0 k100, rather than whatever the automatic conversion of r0 g0 b0 to CMYK gives you.

Comment: e100 makes a good point. And (R0, G0, B0) gets converted to a form of "rich black"--(63C, 52M, 51Y, 100K). You can [read more about the different blacks here](http://www.printernational.org/rich-black-plain-black.php).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, when you change color modes, you should use Photoshop's `Edit`->`Convert to profile` function. This will allow you to map the colors to the new profile in the least-obtrusive way. This should prevent the logo or other asset from noticeably changing colors.

Secondly, the reason people do print designs in CMYK is precisely because it allows them to work in the same color space as the printed result. However, you still need to have 2 things for truly accurate color reproduction:

1. Your monitor has to be calibrated properly. There are various ways of doing this, but usually the best way is using a [colorimeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristimulus_colorimeter) to calibrate your monitor and generate an [ICC profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icc_profile) that can be used to accurately map your monitor's output with other color spaces.
2. Your printer has to be calibrated properly. If you're using a professional printing service, then they should have this part handled.
3. Ideally, you'd also have the ICC profile of the printer/paper you'll be printing with.

If you can get the ICC profile from your printer, then you can go to `View`->`Proof Setup`->`Custom...` and choose the ICC profile you received. Otherwise, the best you can do is soft proof on "Working CMYK".

Though, to be safe, you should also try to get a hard proof or contract proof to make sure things turn out exactly the way you want, especially if it's a large print job for something as important as a business card.

**Note:** Some printing services prefer that all files are kept in RGB. For instance, Blurb—the self-publishing service—requires all images and print files to be sent in RGB format. Perhaps this is because they also create e-books, or perhaps it's to simplify the process for end-users, but that's how they do things. And the ICC profile they provide for soft-proofing is an sRGB profile.

Comment: In the absence of a colorimeter (which can sometimes be rented from a camera shop), one can instead choose colors using Pantone or some other color matching system instead of relying on the screen to render colors. The screen is always going to be off even when calibrated.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. My client has took it to the printers so fingers crossed I got it right in the end. Thanks again

Comment: the reason i would stick in rgb is that the conversion process between profiles is destructive and looses resolution. Technically you should end up with same result as your printer but if something changes in the process then the printer would have a more faithfull conversion to the original if possible when using rgb. Big printers might have many machines with slightly different profiles.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do that. Never, never, never design something to be printed in anything other than the printing mode that will be used. Why? There are many technical reasons. but the main one is that the color modes are not compatible. There is no equivalent CMYK color for a vast range of RGB colors. Also, when you do work in CMYK, don't even bother looking at the monitor. Use a CMYK swatch book printed on the exact same paper stock as you will be printing on, and then get a matchprint or other "contract" proof from the printer. To do otherwise is to prove you are (1) An amateur, not a professional designer, and (2) Not interested in quality (same as 1, really), and (3) made of money, because you will have to eat the cost of bad printing that's your fault.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68516/discussion-on-answer-by-user8356-if-i-make-a-design-in-rgb-mode-and-then-change).