# Why RGB98 printing from photoshop and PDF makes different results?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design

I am having a printing issue between photoshop and print from PDF.

In Photoshop, I print an RGB file with the **Adobe RGB (98)** profile

I tried to make a PDF file from Photoshop with the same configuration,
embedding the **Adobe RGB (98)** profile

When I print with my Epson Pro 9890, I configure both prints with
Adobe RGB 98. In photoshop il **let the printer manage colors**

However, the prints are different, especially the greens come out
totally different. Why?

Is there a way to save my Photoshop print configuration in the PDF?

Comment: Possible related question: [Can you convert a neon RGB color to CMYK for printing?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4464/can-you-convert-a-neon-rgb-color-to-cmyk-for-printing)

Comment: I compare, in a RGB worflow, the results of printing from Photoshop and from a PDF made with Photoshop, and I am asking why the results are different, and how can I make them match.

Comment: Are you working on MAC?

Comment: Are you printing the PDF from preview?

Comment: @Neo Yes I tried from a MAC. I am not sure about this but if "preview" is the name of the PDF reader, it's possible that I am printing from that, yes. This is happening in my school, at home I work on PC and I didn't check if there is a difference yet.

Answer (score 1):

Your printer is not configured correctly, the problem is that your printer is configured to always deal with the color management (you need to change the conversion to automatic).

When you print from preview, the preview/PDF reader applies a color conversion before printing*, it sends the file to the printer and the printer makes another color conversion, which results in incorrect colors.

When you print from Photoshop and you let the printer do the color conversion, Photoshop only sends the file and the printer takes care of the rest, that's why you see the correct colors, because there is only one color conversion.

If you are working with MAC and you want to let the printer manage colors, I suggest you to always print from Photoshop,  that's how I deal with that problem.

*if you have it configured that way.

Comment: I'm gona check that in my school, thank you, seems plausibe.